# How to get values in Check boxes from database using viewbag?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, checkbox, html-helper, viewbag

I am using view bag to get skills. How to get data from viewbag in @html.Checkboxfor().

```
  ViewBag.ListSkill = GetSkills();


  public List<UserViewModel> GetSkills()
    {
        var client = new RestClient(url);
        var request = new RestRequest("api/Users/GetAllSkillList", Method.GET);
        var response = client.Execute<List<UserViewModel>>(request);


        return response.Data;
    }
```

I saw many examples using viewbag but they all using  but I need to write the code in @html.Checkbox. Please Help.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to bind the value to a model?

Comment: @NicoRiff. In model I have already bind country list in Drop down

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following, but it sounds it would be better to you if you bind the checkbox to a model.

```
@Html.CheckBox("yourCheckBox", (bool)ViewBag.yourCheckBoxInfo)
```

Here you have an example: [MVC Binding to checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9580986/mvc-binding-to-checkbox)